# Pymysql Insert Into not working

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, python-2.7, pymysql

I'm running this from PyDev in Eclipse...

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='userid', passwd='password', db='fan')
cur = conn.cursor()
print "writing to db"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO cbs_transactions(leagueID) VALUES ('test val')")
print "wrote to db"
```

The result is, at the top of the Console it says  C:...test.py, and in the Console:

writing to db
wrote to db

So it's not terminating until after the execute command.  But when I look in the table in MySQL it's empty.  A record did not get inserted.

First off, why isn't it writing the record.  Second, how can I see a log or error to see what happened.  Usually there should be some kind of error in red if the code fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database does not update automatically with MySQL and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Did you commit it? `conn.commit()`

Comment: you're my hero!

Answer (score 126):

PyMySQL disable `autocommit` by default, you can add `autocommit=True` to `connect()`:

```py
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='user',
    passwd='passwd',
    db='db',
    autocommit=True
)
```

or call `conn.commit()` after insert

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for autocommit example. Excellent!

Comment: guys in 2019 this is not working when using pymysql in python3.x where's this project so that we can create an issue?

Comment: Something I could not find easily was that you can change the autocommit property later with the method `connection.autocommit(True)`

Comment: This is really helpful, but I cannot believe that they would not do this by default!

Answer (score 4):

You can either do

- `conn.commit()` before calling `close`

or

- enable autocommit via `conn.autocommit(True)` right after creating the connection object.

Both ways have been suggested from various people at a duplication of the question that can be found here: [Database does not update automatically with MySQL and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python)