# pymysql inserting random numbers into a column using python

Tags: python, mysql, random, pymysql

I want to insert random numbers to a MySQL column `rnd_value` with 100 random numbers including and between 1 to 100 using python.

I will generate random numbers from python using

```
random.randrange(1,100)
```

I have added MYSQL query to the database

```
 CREATE SCHEMA `random_values` ;
CREATE TABLE `exercise`.`random_values` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `rnd_value` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '');
```

I use pymysql connector to insert data into MySQL database. Can anyone suggest me to how to insert these random numbers into a MySQL column using python?

Comment: `create table blah
( id int auto_increment primary key,
 theNum int not null
);` .... `insert blah(theNum) values(floor(RAND(100)*4)+1);`

Comment: You should use an INSERT SQL command. Did you read about pymysql and MySQL syntax?

Comment: I'm able to connect MySQL database using pymysql, I'm also able to pass the data to MySQL database, but I want to pass random numbers to column "rnd_value" using python.

Comment: So basically you don't know how to pass a number from python

Comment: I'm able to pass the number to MySQL from python, I want to fill the column "rnd_value" with 100 rows with random numbers generated from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, this code seems to work for me,

```
import pymysql
import random

connection=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='server',
                           db='exercise',charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for i in range (1, 101):
            j=random.randrange(1,100)
            sql = "INSERT INTO exercise.random_values(rnd_value) VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(j))
            connection.commit()

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this simple approach? Connect to the db (assuming localhost and database name is exercise). Then shove the 100 values in 1 by 1?

```
import pymysql
import random

with pymysql.connect(host='localhost', db='exercise') as db:
   for i in random.randrange(1,100):
      qry = "INSERT INTO random_values (rnd_value) VALUES ({})".format(i)
      with db.cursor() as cur:
         cur.execute(qry)
         db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

referred some portions from:
[Pymysql Insert Into not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485332/pymysql-insert-into-not-working)

#### install pymysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

#### in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (`c1` INT NULL,`c2` INT NULL )
```

### python program

```
import pymysql
from random import randint
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user="root")
cursor = conn.cursor()
for i in range (1, 101): # since you want to add 100 entries
  v1 = randint(1,100)
  v2 = randint(1,100)
  sql_statement = "INSERT INTO test.t1(c1, c2) VALUES (" + str(v1) + "," + str(v2)  + ")"
  cursor.execute(sql_statement)
conn.commit() # commit to insert records into database
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

for multiple inserts, use some sort of looping mechanism, or use multi insert method

Then switch over to mysql console and fire select statements to see if insert succeeded

Comment: context managers close open cursors and connections. this is important when multiple users use the same database. closing the cursor and connection after use is advised.

Comment: sure....updated the answer. I did not assume that in the initial scope of the answer.