# What's wrong with my Python code to update MySQL table where ID = an integer?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
>>> print x 
 [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,)]

>>> for i in range(10):
...     if len(x)>0:
...             m = random.choice(x)
...             x.remove(m)
...             y = "%s" %m
...             z = int(y)
...             cur.execute("""UPDATE accounts SET column = 'YES' WHERE userid = %s""", (z, ))
```

This doesn't do anything though. When I view the accounts table, nothing's changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit the changes after the update:

```
db.commit()
```

where `db` is a database connection instance (the result of `connect()` call).

Also see: [Database does not update automatically with MySQL and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python).

Comment: sunnuva! I always forget that.. thank you so much sorry for this ignorant post

Comment: @user262064 You might want to create your cursor like `with connection as cursor:` immediately above the `for` loop. Then it will automatically `commit()` on success or `rollback()` on error.