# Inserting data into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I'm trying to execute the following code

```
for counter in range(0, len(weatherData) - 1):
    string = 'INSERT INTO weather VALUES(' + str((weatherData[counter])[0:]) +');'
    print(string)
    cur.execute(string)
```

All the the values and data are printed correctly and everything seems to work as there is no errors, however when I check the data base its empty.

Comment: Related: [Database does not update automatically with MySQL and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/384228/190597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do [**`commit`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) after insertion complete.

```
for counter in range(0, len(weatherData) - 1):
    ....
connection_object.commit()
```

BTW, you'd better to use parameter-passing style instead of build query string yourself:

```
for data in weatherData:
    sql = 'INSERT INTO weather VALUES(%s)'
    cur.execute(sql, [data])
```

Comment: the data in the weatherData variable is a list, so would I need to wrap everything with quotes?

Comment: @user2672738, I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain by showing the code?

Comment: I have the code on github i cleaned up the code a bit but the concept hasn't changed :https://github.com/akhilcjacob/weather_station/blob/master/dataToSQL.py

Comment: @user2672738, Ah, I got it. You don't need to quote the string. If you pass the string with parameter passing style, db api will care of quoting.

Answer (score 0):

The loop can be simplified as follows

```
for counter, row in weatherData:
    string = 'INSERT INTO weather VALUES(' + str(row) + ');'
```

and you'll need to commit afterwards

EDIT - added counter, which is a count of the for loop
EDIT2 - using row 
EDIT3 - removed [0:] from end of string which doesn't do anything

Comment: `row[0:] == row`, no need to use `[0:]` :)