# SQL insert doesn't work (no errors appear)

Tags: python, mysql

Hi i am creating a queries through python functions.

When i am trying to insert certain values : a succesfull insert appears but my query doesn't show up when i search the database by hand .

The code is this:

```
@post('/store_artist')
def store_artist():
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='songs')
c = conn.cursor();
c.execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
c.execute("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
artist_name = request.forms.get('artist_name')
artist_surname = request.forms.get('artist_surname')
artist_bday =  request.forms.get('artist_bday')
artist_id =  request.forms.get('artist_id')
c.execute(("INSERT INTO kalitexnis (ar_taut,onoma,epitheto, etos_gen) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"),(int(artist_id),artist_name,artist_surname,int(artist_bday))) 
result = c.fetchall()
return "Artist info successfully stored"
```

Any idea ?    Thank you

Comment: Are each of your values filled and not empty?

Comment: I'm guessing, so not an answer: You need `conn.commit()`. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python

Comment: yep . Just printed them in python to be sure

Comment: @Robᵩ youuuuu are right :) Thank you man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `conn.commit()` after every `insert` and `update` query for the changes to be saved into the db.

Alternatively, you could call `conn.autocommit(True)`, then the changes will be immediately saved in the db.

Comment: Is it `c.commit()` or `conn.commit()`, or does it matter?

Comment: @Robᵩ `conn.commit()` is what I have always used based on the tutorials I read a while back

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks, it is indeed `conn.commit()`. I will update my answer