# Python MySQL insert

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem with an insert in python. All the attributes are correct and it gives no errors. Here is my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="ueberwachung") #Datenbank connection
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tereignisse VALUES('1002', '2016-12-02','18:34:15','/var/www/html/videos/2016-11-0103:21:13', '0')") 
cur.close()
db.close()
```

Edit: Sorry I forgot the problem. So problem: It doesn't write anything into the table.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Errors? Output? Anything? Computer making beeping noises or catching on fire?

Comment: I edited it now thanks

Comment: It doesn't write anything because you don't `commit()` the transaction

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit the transaction before closing the connection:

```
db.commit()
cur.close()
db.close()
```