# Using MySQL commands in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I just got into SQL to do some data science and was wondering why my code was running but not affecting the MySQL database in any way. I am using pycharm and the MySQLdb module.

```
 import MySQLdb
 db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                      user="root",
                      passwd="********", #Password blocked
                      db="test")
 cur = db.cursor()
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM movies")
 cur.execute("Update movies set genre = 'action' where id = 1")
 for row in cur.fetchall() :
     print row[0], " ", row[1], " ", row[2]
```

My code runs and returns no errors, but when I delete the

```
 cur.execute("Update movies set genre = 'action' where id = 1")
```

line it just prints out the table the as it was before. Just for reference, here is the table:

1   Interstellar   sci-fi

2   Thor: Ragnarok   action

3   Thor: The Dark World   action

How can I make the commands in python actually affect the table? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit changes made to the table using `cur.commit()`

[Database does not update automatically with MySQL and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384228/database-does-not-update-automatically-with-mysql-and-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cur.commit()` to commit the changes to the database. Also, you should close your database using `cur.close()` once you're finished.